# Amazon MWS API Address format for CreateInboundShipmentPlan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, amazon-mws

Using the Ruby Gem - [Peddler](https://github.com/hakanensari/peddler) to access the MWS API. We have to send the ship from address. The documentation says it needs to be a hash, but I can't get this to work..

```
ship_from_address = {
  name: "Schmo",
  addressline1: "929 Whatever Dr.",
  city: "Fun Town",
  stateorprovincecode: "XX",
  postalcode: "12345"
}
```

And here is the actual call to the API with the client setup correctly, because I can access other data where the request is more simple..

```
plan = client.create_inbound_shipment_plan(ship_from_address,    
  inbound_shipment_plan_request_items)
```

And here is the link to the [amazon documentation](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_CreateInboundShipmentPlan.html)..

This is what the format of the address field looks like when I request it from the API..

```
{"ShipmentData"=>{"member"=>{"LabelPrepType"=>"SELLER_LABEL",
"DestinationFulfillmentCenterId"=>"IND2", "ShipFromAddress"=>
{"City"=>"XXX", "CountryCode"=>"XX", "PostalCode"=>"12345", 
"Name"=>"Schmo", "AddressLine1"=>"3434 Smitherens Rd.", 
"StateOrProvinceCode"=>"YY", "AddressLine2"=>"#13A"}, 
"ShipmentId"=>"FBA37ZLXXX", "AreCasesRequired"=>"false", 
"ShipmentName"=>"2015-12-22 09:58", "ShipmentStatus"=>"IN_TRANSIT"}}}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to stick to conventions of naming keys in the hash. The keys of the hash are converted to uppercase, so `addressline1` will become `Addressline1`, but it should be `AddressLine1`. Try to rename the keys like so:

```
ship_from_address = {
  name: "Schmo",
  address_line_1: "929 Whatever Dr.",
  city: "Fun Town",
  state_or_province_code: "XX",
  postal_code: "12345"
}
```

Pay attention to how keys are named in specs of Peddler gem – https://github.com/hakanensari/peddler/blob/master/test/integration/test_fulfillment_inbound_shipment.rb#L5 I think this the cause of the problem.

Comment: Wow!! Jeiwan you are the ONLY person who got back to me across 5 forums! Thank you.. it wasn't exactly the answer, but I took those tests and just copied it exactly, Struct and all.. and it worked!!!! Thank you!!

Comment: Oh, yep, it requires a Struct, not Hash.